# calculating sum of a column in list<class>

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am trying to calculate a sum of hours in a timecard class for a passed project argument. I'm new enough to LINQ, MVC, Navigation properties, and Lambda expressions that I keep chasing my tail trying to get this to work in my ViewModel constructor.

I've got the following:
ProjectTimecardViewModel.cs

```
public class ProjectTImecardViewModel
{
    public int? ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalHours { get; set; }
    public List<Timecard> Timecards { get; set; }

    public ProjectTImecardViewModel(Project project)
    {
        ProjectId = project.ProjectId;
        ProjectName = project.ProjectName;
        Timecards = project.Timecards;

        //equivalent of what I want in SQL
        // TotalHours = SELECT SUM(Hours) FROM [Timecards] WHERE ProjectId = @ProjectId
        // best guess at what I want in LINQ
        // TotalHours = (from hours in Timecards where ProjectId == project.ProjectId select hours).Sum();
    }
}
```

Timecard.cs

```
public class Timecard
{
    public int TimecardId { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public decimal Hours { get; set; }
    public int? ProjectId { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
    public TimecardTask TimecardTask { get; set; }
}
```

Project.cs

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    ...
    public List<Timecard> Timecards { get; set; }

    public Project()
    {
        Timecards = new List<Timecard>();
    }
}
```

I know I could create a class that initializes my dbContext and figure out the equivalent LINQ syntax that way, but the only way I've figured out how to do that exposes my connection string in code. For what it's worth, this is code-first EF Core connecting to a MSSQL Server.

I know this syntax doesn't work exactly, but is there something similar I can use either with the existing navigation properties or lambda expressions on the existing classes to `TotalHours = (from hours in Timecards.Hours where ProjectId == project.ProjectId select hours).Sum();`? As is I get the red squiggle under Hours because List doesn't contain a definition for Hours. Or is there another way I can make a List of Hours and run the above LINQ against that?

Comment: Something like `double hoursSum = Timecards.Where(tc => tc.ProjectId == id).Sum(tc => tc.Hours);`?

Comment: if you want to corret your query it must be `TotalHours = (from card in Timecards where card.ProjectId == project.ProjectId select card.Hours).Sum();`

Comment: Why are you storing the `ProjectId` in the `ProjectTImecardViewModel`? why not the complete `Project` reference?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen The Project ID and Project Name are in the <h2></h2> block of the view as the title of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want to use `Sum`:

```
TotalHours = Timecards.Sum(c => c.Hours);
```

Or if you need the project ID piece:

```
TotalHours = Timecards.Where(c => c.ProjectId == ProjectId).Sum(c => c.Hours);
```

Trying to get that into query syntax probably isn't worth the effort.

Comment: `TotalHours = Timecards.Where(c => c.ProjectId.HasValue && c.ProjectId.Value == ProjectId).Sum(c => c.Hours);`  you should check the nullable int _(int? ProjectId)_ with HasValue.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I believe for comparison purposes this is actually safe. A implicit cast will be performed against any actual `int` and if `ProjectId` is null any comparison (except against null) will return false (verified in C# interactive)

Comment: This should get me there. I tried the latter of the two and my DisplayFor on my view is coming up as 0.00, but I think that is more likely due to a bad navigation somewhere. The lambda syntax was something I was hoping to get to.

Comment: Yeah, forgot the .Include(p => p.Timecards) in my controller. Works like a charm.